# Mechanize to submit and read response

Tags: python, response, mechanize

I am using mechanize in python to submit a form and print out the response but it does not seem to work

```
import mechanize

# The URL to this service
URL = 'http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/bidsearch.php'


def main():
    # Create a Browser instance
    b = mechanize.Browser()
    # Load the page
    b.open(URL)
    # Select the form
    b.select_form(nr=0)
    # Fill out the form
    b['ddlfinancialyear'] = '2015-2016'
    b.submit()
    b.response().read()
```

What I am trying to do is submit a form using the url 'sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/bidsearch.php';, and when the form is submitted( by trying to pass value '2015-2016' to 'ddfinancialyear' control) another page should be returned as a response and I am not getting any output.

Comment: You'll need to tell us exactly what "does not seem to work" means. What happens, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: What I am trying to do is submit a form using the url 'http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/bidsearch.php', and when the form is submitted( by trying to pass value '2015-2016' to 'ddfinancialyear' control) another page should be returned as a response and I am not getting any output.

Comment: Did you try checking what `response.code` says?

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning the `b.submit` before reading it:

```
S = b.submit()
S.read()
```